# Are Kerberos and e-commerce inconsistent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, e-commerce, kerberos

I recently read about Kerberos and its great algorithm to securely authenticate user.

But the "drawback" of Kerberos is that it requires credentials (calls "principals") to be added manually directly from the authentication server (implemented with Kerberos so).

So, unless I ignore it, it's impossible to use a classic form in an e-commerce to add a NEW user to Kerberos. Indeed, obviously, it will waste Kerberos principle because credentials would be sent over the network, even if they are encrypted with SSL...

Could you confirm me or not that Kerberos cannot be use for classical Web Site requiring each user to create themselves adding their own login/pass? That means without need of Kerberos server's administrator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create user from WebSite and include them into Kerberos as a principal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739974/create-user-from-website-and-include-them-into-kerberos-as-a-principal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, in terms of technical capabilities, use Kerberos as the backing store for authentication information and still support username and password over SSL.  It's not the ideal Kerberos model, since it means that a system other than the local system the user is sitting in front of gets a copy of the password.  But that just means that you're not using the full security capabilities of Kerberos; it doesn't mean that Kerberos won't work.  It may still be convenient to use Kerberos for other reasons.

One of the dirty little secrets of Kerberos is that nearly every site that has deployed it on a large-scale basis accepts username and password over SSL for at least some applications and validates the username and password on the server.  There just isn't any other good way to do it in a lot of cases.  This is particularly true of web applications.  While many web browsers do support SPNEGO via Negotiate-Auth to do a real Kerberos authentication, this doesn't work in a wide variety of situations (no Kerberos locally on the system, kiosk system, phone device with no local Kerberos libraries, etc.).

(I'm the Kerberos administrator for Stanford University and also the maintainer of our web authentication system, which is based on Kerberos but still, for most users, takes username and password over SSL and verifies them on a central web login server.)